# Exception from void method to a servlet

Tags: exception, servlets

In my database access objects I have a void method which is executed by a servlet:

My dao:

```
public void saveGL(glmaintenancebean glm) {
        username = glm.getUsername();
        date = glm.getDate();
        code = glm.getCode();
        branch = glm.getBranch();
        currency = glm.getCurrency();
        description = glm.getDescription();
        type = glm.getType();
        String bankid = getBankId();
        Connection conn;
        try{
          conn =  db.getDbConnection();
          String sql = "insert into gl_master (GL_CODE,GL_BRANCH,GL_CURRENCY,GL_DESC,GL_TYPE,BANK_ID,"
                  + "RCRE_USER,RCRE_DATE,LMOD_USER,LMOD_DATE) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,"
                  + "to_date(?,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),?,to_date(?,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'))";
          PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          ps.setString(1, code.toUpperCase());
          ps.setString(2, branch.toUpperCase());
          ps.setString(3, currency.toUpperCase());
          ps.setString(4, description.toUpperCase());
          ps.setString(5, type.toUpperCase());
          ps.setString(6, bankid.toUpperCase());
          ps.setString(7, username.toUpperCase());
          ps.setString(8, date);
          ps.setString(9, username.toUpperCase());
          ps.setString(10, date);
          ps.executeUpdate();
        }catch(Exception asd){
            System.out.println(asd.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My servlet;

```
glmaintenancedao gld = new glmaintenancedao();//My Dao
            if (gld.glAlreadyExists(glm) == false) {
                if (gld.usersolandenteredsolMismatch(glm) == false) {
                    gld.saveGL(glm);//My void method called
                    request.setAttribute("succ", "General Ledger added Succesfully");
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/gl/glmaintenanance_succ.jsp").forward(request, response);
                } else {
                    request.setAttribute("succ", "User not Authorised to add Gl In another Branch!!");
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/gl/glmaintenanance_succ.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }
```

I need to report to the user any error arising from the void dao method say all ORA Errors say invalid Column name, table or view does not exists.

In my code if a database ora error is encouuntered the system still displys general ledger added successfully:

Amy ideas will be appreaciated.

Comment: i think the 8th column is datetime datatype and you are using setString method.This may be causing error

Comment: No sir, this is not what is causing the error though I agree it may cause an error. My question is if that error you are talking about happens in that method, i need to be able to show it to the user through the servlet. This error currently show on my aaplication server logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You are catching all exceptions in the DAO, that is why they are not reported back.*

You can:

1. Modify `saveGL()` to declare it throws `SQLException`
2. Modify the `catch` clause to wrap the `SQLException` into an application specific exception (i.e. an Exception class you have created) and rethrow it; this exception may be checked, so `saveGL()` must declare it, or unchecked (`RuntimeException`).

Handling the exception:

1. Catch it in the servlet
2. Define exception handlers in web.xml and show an error page

Comment: I frank do not understand this Part : `You are catching all exceptions in the DAO, that is why they are not reported back.` Does this mean I remove the try catch statement in My method?

Comment: Not in any account! It means that `catch(Exception asd){/*print it*/}` will catch all exceptions and the function will return as if the exception did not happen (with the only evidence it did happen in the console). So you either (pseudocode) `catch(...){throw SomethingElse}` or do not catch anything, declare the exception in the method: `public void saveGL(...) throws ...`, and catch it in the servlet.

Comment: Ok Will try this and let you know how I got along thanks for the help.